# How do i use this Escape Hex Character to be implement on StringBuilder ESC X using C#

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, epson, unicode-escapes

Hello I'm sending a bunch of strings to a thermal printer i have epson and i'm using stringbuilder for it. so far i manage to do by changing the text to it's normal weight into bold by doing this

```
const char ESC = '\x1b';

// Initialize printer
sb.Append(ESC + "@");

sb.Append(ESC + "E" + (char)1);  <-- Bold Weight it Works
// Align center
sb.Append(ESC + "a" + (char)1); <-- it works too
```

but now i wanted to Increase the Font Size of the Text i check on the manual of Epson
it gave me a formula like this:

```
Select font by pitch and point: ESC X m nn <-- so i tried it on my code by doing this:

sb.Append(ESC + "X"+ (char)15); it did not work but there is no error on code.
sb.Append(ESC + "X"+ (int)15); also tried this still the same.
```

may i ask anyone knows how to implement this so i can change the font size of the text?

Comment: "ESC X m nn" seems to specify two values (m and nn), and you only supplied one?

Comment: In addition to Hans Kesting's comment, the version of the [ESC/P manual](https://files.support.epson.com/pdf/general/escp2ref.pdf) I found says that only certain sizes are available, and 15 is not among them.

Comment: how do you code it then can you show just a sample of how it was done?

sb.Append(ESC + "x" + (int)10 + (char)1 + (char)0); <-- should i do like this?

Comment: Codes Below still didn't work nothing is change in the print result.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
const char ESC_CHAR = (char)27;
:
// Note no spaces between command elements
var cmd = $"{ESC_CHAR}X{(char)m}{(char)nn}";

// for old C# (no string interpolation) use your original approach 
// (or string.Format() for better readability)
var cmdAlt = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}", ESC, (char)m, (char)nn);
```

I suggest you encapsulate this in a `string PrintCommandString()` function, with overloads for commands with no parameters, 1 parameter, 2 params etc

Note also @AndrewMorton's comment.  If nn is 2 bytes you may have to split nn - perhaps `(char)(byte)(nn)` and `(char)(nn >> 8))`

In summary

```
public static string PrintCommandString(char cmdChar, byte m, ushort nn)
{
  const char ESC = (char)27;
  // note Littel Endian implies low byte before high byte
  return  $"{ESC}{cmdChar}{(char)(byte)m}{(char)(byte)nn}{(char)(nn >> 8)}";
}
```

called

```
var cmd = PrintCommandString('X', 36, 0);
```

or because you want to use StringBuilder...

```
public static string PrintCommandString(char cmdChar, byte m, ushort nn)
{
  var sb = new StringBuilder();
  sb.Append((char)27).Append(cmdChar).Append((char)m).Append((char)(nn >> 8));
  return sb.ToString();
}
```

The trick is to get those `m` and `nn` values right

Comment: `m` represents one byte, `nn` represents an integer from 0–32767 in little-endian format.

Comment: May I suggest to declare `m` and `nn` in your code sample, so it's more clear.

Comment: if im going to use it to stringbuilder sir what would it look like? cause what i have done is similar like this one i set the text string to bold. like this

const char ESC = '\x1b';

sb.Append(ESC + "E" + (char)1);
sb.AppendLine(" " + OrderLst.Text + "\n");

this here set the print to bold weight

how do i use the code you showed similar to like this. using stringbuilder

Comment: also i tried the codes above it didn't increase the font it just printed the $ symbol beside the data

Comment: I've added a `StringBuilder()` sample to my answer.

Comment: let me try this then.. hope i could have send you the output but i cant post an image on this post yet.

Comment: i also check this articles:
http://support2.epson.net/manuals/english/page/epl_n4000plus/ref_g/APCOM_3.HTM

page 104 of the PDF:
https://files.support.epson.com/pdf/general/escp2ref.pdf

it says i just need this ESC X nn
cause i try also to compare on the ESC E (char)1 i had which is working and it's similar to the document

Comment: @MikAA :  In that second link page C-97 describes ESC X, page C-104 ESC g.  To vary point size and pitch together you must work with ESC X.  ESC g needs no parameters (a shortcut for one common pitch-size combination).   On C-97 check under the heading "Parameter range" AND under "Notes" to make sure you are working with a qualified printer and within the allowed parameter values (particularly that you have a font selected that is scalable on your printer).  Then try - say - `var cmd = PrintCommandString('X', 18 /*5 CPI*/, 40 /*20 points*/); // (if my arithmetic is correct;-)`

Comment: it's not printing anymore the string but still doesn't make the text larger. nothing takes effect